# Display section data in UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am new to sectioned UITableVIew.My Problem is I have an array called stringsArray which is having the strings like

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWitObjects:@"apple1",@"apple2",@"ball",@"cat",@"cat2",nil]; //I have many strings.
```

I need to display the data like the below

I need to display apple1,apple2 under the section A
I need to display ball under the section B like this.

Can any body help me to do this.

Comment: You have a full solution to your problem in [this link](http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/)

Comment: Below are the two good tutorials you will get your answer http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/ http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-sectioned-table-view.html hope this helps

Comment: It will become much easier to do and understand if you change the structure of your data so that each object in `dataArray` is also a `NSMutableArray`.  Each array inside `dataArray` would represent one section and would contain only the strings for that section's rows.

Comment: Save data for each section in a different NSMutable array. You will also be able to count the number of rows to be displayed in each section more easily if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get your strings in the arrays stringsForSection1 and stringsForSection2. Change the names to  your liking ;) Then you implement the UITableViewDataSourceProtocol. You are required to implement 2 methods:

-tableView:numberForRowsInSection:

-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Here is a link to the reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html
In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, the (NSIndexPath *)indexPath will contain a section- and a row-property. Depending on these values, you can load your data from stringsForSection1 or stringsForSection2 like so:

```
if(indexPath.section==1){
    cell.textLabel.text = [stringsForSection1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else if(indexPath.section==2){
    cell.textLabel.text = [stringsForSection2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Have fun